# R readHTMLTable: Error failed to load external entity

Tags: r

I am trying to read a HTML table using the XML command `readHTMLTable`. It is information about options in the Eurex page. When i run the code:

```
info<-readHTMLTable("http://www.eurexchange.com/action/exchange-en/155392-31606/31608/quotesSingleViewOption.do?callPut=Call&maturityDate=201312",which=1)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: failed to load external entity "http://www.eurexchange.com/action/exchange-en/155392-31606/31608/quotesSingleViewOption.do?callPut=Call&maturityDate=201312"
```

I have the correct packages installed and the last r version.

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Runs fine for me. Could just be a problem with your internet connection that's preventing you from loading the page cleanly...?

Comment: I have tried it with another computer in the same network and it works perfectly. I don´t understand.

Comment: @jccigh This looks like the web page had a temporary issue (with an invalid entity). Are you still having this problem?

Comment: That URL (as of 2014-04-14) is a 404; is it still happening with other URLs? If so, can you post the R version and XML package version for each of the working and non-working machine?

Answer (score 0):

Use function GET of package httr to retrieve html content:

```
info<-readHTMLTable(rawToChar(GET("http://www.eurexchange.com/action/exchange-en/155392-31606/31608/quotesSingleViewOption.do?callPut=Call&maturityDate=201312")$content),which=1)
```