# R Error using readHTMLTable

Tags: r

I am using the following code:

```
url  = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=DIA&m=2013-07"

library(XML)
tabs = readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: failed to load external entity "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=DIA&m=2013-07"
```

When I use the url in the browser it works fine. So, what am I doing incorrect here?

Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: It works for me too. Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629026/r-readhtmltable-error-failed-to-load-external-entity, it sounds like this might be an issue with your internet connection. Are you able to load the page in a browser?

Comment: Yes I am able to load the page fine in a browser. So, my internet connection is fine I assume.

Comment: Can you run `library(RCurl); tabs = getURL(url)` without triggering an error?

Comment: Proxy setting
try methods here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r ,may help you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's difficult to know for sure since I can't replicate your error, but according the package's author (see http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.mac/2284), XML's methods for getting web content are pretty minimalistic. A workaround is to use `RCurl` to get the content and `XML` to parse it:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url <- "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=DIA&m=2013-07"

tabs <- getURL(url)
tabs <- readHTMLTable(tabs, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Or, if `RCurl` still throws an error, try the `httr` package:

```
library(httr)

tabs <- GET(url)
tabs <- readHTMLTable(rawToChar(tabs$content), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error as above "failed to load external entity" when using
url <- "http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/a-to-z-series-index.html"
doc <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternal=TRUE)

I came across this and another post on the topic, which didn't solve my problem. This code worked before. I then realized that I was on corporate VPN. I got off the VPN and tried again and it worked. So, being on VPN might be another reason why you would get the above error. Getting off VPN solves it.